# Why is the system telling me that I don't have Python 3.10 in my system when I do?

Tags: python, django, docker, version

I'm using pipenv for my virutal enviroment and am trying to install psycopg2 in Docker. However, when I try to install it, I get the following error.

```
docker-compose exec web pipenv install psycopg2-binary
Warning: Python 3.10 was not found on your system...
Neither 'pyenv' nor 'asdf' could be found to install Python.
You can specify specific versions of Python with:
$ pipenv --python path/to/python
```

I checked the python version within the virtual enviroment and it gives me 3.10.2.

```
% python --version
Python 3.10.2
```

I also checked the python version outside of the virtual enviroment(the system) but here, it gives me python 3.8.8 as default.

```
python --version
Python 3.8.8
```

Despite this, when I type python3.10 in the command line, it shows me that I have it installed in the system, so I'm unsure why it says 3.10 isn't found on my system.

```
python3.10
Python 3.10.2 (v3.10.2:a58ebcc701, Jan 13 2022, 14:50:16) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang- 
1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Lastly, this all happens when I'm in using conda activate. I need conda activate for pipenv to work. When I do "conda deactivate" and type python --version , it gives me the following:

```
conda deactivate
% python --version
Python 3.10.2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `docker-compose exec` to install packages in a container: that work will get lost as soon as the container exits.  Do you have a `Dockerfile` that demonstrates the issue a little more reproducibly?  Do you need both Pipfile and Conda at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Using python in condo you can create a new env by typing 'condo create --name pyhtonversion' which version you want in the new env, and by it just create it.

Lastly do the 'condo activate envname'.
It will work and will be hassle free in which you can maintain the shells with different python version as per the project requirements.